# Displacement/Bump mapping with repeated parts (Octopus Tentacles)

Tags: mesh, displacement

sorry for any incorrect terminology;

I want to make a low-poly octopus with a high-detail displacement/bump(?) map applied to the mesh. At the moment, I've completed the low-poly meshes for the body, and a single tentacle (which I plant to duplicate). I have not yet attempted to create any detailed mapping to either.

Because each tentacle is identical, I'd ideally like to do the details on one, make copies of it for the rest, and attach them to the body, so there is one smooth mesh with a smooth detailed layer.

My question:
1- Is it possible to join separate objects with their own displacement maps together as one object with a single displacement map?

2- If not, what is the best way to handle this task (without manually detailing each of the 8 tentacles)?

Comment: The bump is at the material level, so yes you can join them as they will all share the same material and UV map (keep the same UV map's name for all)

Comment: So theoretically, I could make one tentacle, give it a bumpmap, then copy and paste it a few times to make exact duplicates and arrange them on the body, then merge then all into one object with one bumpmap?

Comment: Yes. All copies will have the same UV map, mapping the same bump texture, used in the same material shared between them. And that will stay true when joint in one mesh. Give it a try on a simple mesh...